# Rust Ndarray Slice from vec/list of integers

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-ndarray

I need to take a slice from ArrayBase ( ndarray crate ) with particular indexes (ie not range, not a single integer, but a collection of integers).

Example:

```rust
let ar = arr2(&[[1.,2.,3., 4.,5.,6.], [7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12.]]);
```

From: https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html#indexing-and-slicing I see that s! macro helps to build a slice from integers and ranges. However, what if I want to build a slice from an arbitraty vec (which I don't know upfront)?

Eg, I want to take first, fourth and fifth columns, so I want something like:

```rust
dbg!(ar.slice(s![.., &[0, 3, 4] ));
```

I'd like to get an array like this:

```rust
[[1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [7.0, 10.0, 11.0]]
```